# How do I use socket.io with node.js without installing node.js or socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I know I can just run the node executable to run node, but how I can write using the socket.io library without installing it?

Comment: What do you mean by installing it? 

It should be possible to manually link to the library without fetching via NPM, however you would have to include all it's dependencies manually.

Answer (score 1):

If You are talking about npm, You can actually include the library manually. Also check for the required file which got to be included.

Comment: So instead of `require('socket.io')` it'll just be `require(path_to_socket.io.js)`?